# AngularJS and ngRepeat - insert additional element every n repeats

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a structure where every 7 repeated divs there is an additional div inserted. This div has to belong to the parent, and not be a child of one of the repeated divs.

It isn't enough just to change class, the entire content will be different and entirely different ngShow logic will be used with the additional div.

So for example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="special-child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="special-child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="special-child"></div>
</div>
```

That example uses a specific number of divs, the ngRepeat could be any number. It's also important the last result of the ngRepeat puts in an additional div after it, even if it isn't an exact multiple of 7.

The current ngRepeat logic I'm using is:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" ng-repeat="o in data"></div>
  <div class="special-child"></div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work properly as the additional div is only inserted once after all the repeated divs.

**Update with working example**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" ng-repeat-start="o in data"></div>
  <div class="special-child" ng-if="( $index + 1 ) % 7 == 0 || $last" ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

This solution requires AngularJS 1.2+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need something close to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in data">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div ng-if="$index % 7 == 0" class="special-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas of a way that doesn't require repeating the parent? Wanted that as a last resort because it means a lot of CSS changes if I need to add an additional div in-between!

Comment: In answer to my question. ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end appear to be the answer (AngularJS 1.2+).

I put ng-repeat-start on the child and ng-repeat-end on the special-child and used a variation of the ng-if as suggested, which gives the result without repeating the parent!